# emulator is not launching my project

Tags: android, emulation, manifest

```
[2013-03-19 08:52:49 - GEARS] Performing sync
[2013-03-19 08:52:50 - GEARS] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'sdfs'
[2013-03-19 08:52:50 - GEARS] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'sdfs'
[2013-03-19 08:52:54 - GEARS] ------------------------------
[2013-03-19 08:52:54 - GEARS] Android Launch!
[2013-03-19 08:52:54 - GEARS] adb is running normally.
[2013-03-19 08:52:54 - GEARS] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-03-19 08:52:54 - GEARS] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2013-03-19 08:52:54 - GEARS] Performing sync
[2013-03-19 08:52:54 - GEARS] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'sdfs'
[2013-03-19 08:52:54 - GEARS] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'sdfs'
```

I'm making an android app and after editing it I encounter this problem. It has no errors but it doesn't launch either. Is my problem with my manifest or launch activity?

**Updated Manifest:**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.bpi.gears.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.main" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="com.bpi.gears.home"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home" >
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.bpi.gears.profile"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_profile" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I still can't run my app.

Comment: Did you add your Activity in your manifest file?

Comment: should i add the home activity?because it says waiting for home..
    [2013-03-19 08:53:39 - GEARS] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
    [2013-03-19 08:54:47 - GEARS] emulator-5556 disconnected! Cancelling 'sync'!
    [2013-03-19 08:57:43 - GEARS] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
    [2013-03-19 08:57:43 - GEARS] Uploading GEARS.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
    [2013-03-19 08:57:45 - GEARS] Installing GEARS.apk...

Comment: il post another question manifest too long

Comment: @ElefantPhace, it's not Martin who's rejecting your edits. It's part of the edit approval process.

Comment: no it is him, because he keeps changing his original post at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same activity defined twice. remove this and try:

```
 <activity
    android:name="com.bpi.gears.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
 </activity>
```

You have this in your manifest:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.main" />
```

It needs to be like this:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

you have `main` instead of `MAIN`

Comment: is your MainActivity saved as MainActivity.java?

Comment: no sir i have a separate MainAcvtivity.java file...i have 3 java files
home profile and MainActivity files..

Comment: so your MainActivity is MainActivity.java which is what I asked.

Comment: Look above at my edit, change lowercase main to all uppercase and it should work

Comment: yeah il rerun it i didnt notice that one coz it didnt show an error my pc is a bit slow so please bear with me

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
   
 } this is from my MainActivity should i make main to MAIN?

Comment: what? no... in your manifest! look at my answer again, I'll make it simpler for you

Comment: you don't have to close the emulator each time, just leave it open

Comment: next time i wont close it..so slow

Comment: @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) { getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); return true; }
i have this block on all java files should main stay main for all java files just asking havent load yet lol

Comment: that's fine, that has nothing to do with what I was talking about in your manifest file

Comment: im just asking about it...im confused with it im thinking its where i make my mistake..im not sure though..it has no error by the way

Comment: too bad i didnt launch...hahaha i really have a mistake somehere in the codes

Comment: did you change your manifest as i suggested above? changing lowercase intent.action.main to intent.action.MAIN?

Comment: yes i did that one...<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

Comment: try running it on your phone

Comment: what do you mean run it on phone?save it on phone?i wont run on emulator i think i wont run in phone il be doing some more changes lol i hope i will run now